# Filtrador de productos de mysql

Tags: jquery, laravel

es la primera vez que estoy haciendo un filtrador de productos con checkboxes + AJAX. Creo que no voy mal, teniendo en cuenta que me lo estoy haciendo yo a base de prueba y error.
Tengo varias dudas, pero la más importante es que una vez que obtengo la query con el resultado como imprimo el resultado donde toca???

**HTML donde están las categorias**

```
<div class="categorias">
  @foreach ($categorias as $cat)
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" id="categoria" value="{{ $cat->id }}">
      <label class="form-check-label">{{ $cat->name }}</label>
    </div> 
  @endforeach
</div>
```

**AJAX donde extraigo los valores distintos de los checkboxes**

```
$('[name="categoria[]"], [name="subcategoria[]"]').click(function() {
      
      var categoria = $('[name="categoria[]"]:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
      }).get();
      var subcategoria = $('[name="subcategoria[]"]:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
      }).get();
      

      var url = 'productos/filtros';
      $.ajax({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {'categoria': categoria,
               'subcategoria': subcategoria },

               beforeSend: function(){
                $("#filtrados").html("<div class='ui active inline loader'></div>")
               },
               success: function (resultado){
                  $("#filtrados").html(resultado);
               }
      
      });

      console.log(categoria, subcategoria);
```

De momento traigo los valores de categorías y subcategorias, no pongo el html de subcategorias por no engordar mucho la pregunta, es igual que al de categorías.

**Luego en mi controlador**

```
public function filtros(Request $request)
    {
        $cate = $_POST['categoria'];

        $productos = Product::with('variaciones')
                ->join('categories', 'products.categoria', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategoria', '=', 'subcategories.id')
                ->join('marcas', 'products.proveedor', '=', 'marcas.id')
                ->select('products.*', 'categories.name as nameCategoria', 'subcategories.name as nameSubcategoria', 'marcas.empresa as proveedor')
                ->where('products.categoria', $cate)
                ->latest('id')
                ->paginate(6);

        dd($productos);
        return $productos;
    }
```

De momento solo estoy probando con `categoria`, se que habrán vario errores pero quiero ir solucionandomelos yo. Solo necesito saber como imprimo el resultado remplazando al que sale de forma nativa.

Comment: Has visto ese `Request $request` que tienes en el método? Pues ahí deberías tener todos los datos, no usar las variables post. Prueba a coger los datos así: `$data = $request->only("categoria", subcategoria");` y podrás acceder a ellos con `$data["categoria"]`

Comment: Hola @Benito-B gracias por tu respuesta. Además de corregir lo que me dices, como imprimo los datos en la vista, si es un AJAX??

Comment: `return response()->json(["status" => true, "data" => $arrayConObjetos]);` y en success puedes parsear el json que recibes y en data tendrás toda la información

Comment: Entonces en el success tengo que crear la respuesta en JavaScript??? si es así hay forma de hacerlo en PHP de laravel?

Comment: Claro. Perdona es la costumbre de devolver json en las API. Puedes devolver un string con el html ya montado con `return $variableConElHtml;`

Comment: Entonces tendría que concatenar el HTML en el controlado y mandar la respuesta en HTML no? no se que opción es mejor, culaquiera de las dos se me complica

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113367/discussion-between-benito-b-and-miguel).